# Resolve a URL request containing .jsp in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a Spring Web MVC project. I want to handle request with with .jsp in the url such that all request with .jsp in the URL are handled by the same controller.

Following is the url pattern I am using in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The annotation in the Controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
```

With this I am able to resolve URL of the form  `http://localhost:8080/project/welcome`

But not this one : `http://localhost:8080/project/welcome.jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very uncommon requirement for a spring MVC controller, but spring **is** a very versatile tool.

You can try this  (untested ...) :

```
@RequestMapping("/{name}.jsp")
public ModelAndView jspHandler(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
...
```

The controller will get all `*.jsp` requests and you will find in `name` variable the real name by which it has been called

Answer (score 1):

You can using this :

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/welcome","/welcome.jsp"})
```

Comment: This would work, but what I would like to do is run that particular controller for all types of .jsp request. i.e http://localhost:8080/project/abc.jsp should also be handled.

Comment: you can also use regex to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy you can do using below technique

Add below code in your controller

```
@RequestMapping("/{jspName}.jsp")
     public String allRequestProcess(@PathVariable("jspName") String jspName) {
        System.out.println("JSP Page Name : " + jspName);
     }
```

but it will hard to handle every such request in one controller.
try to avoid such situation. Better to use some else than .jsp